# Is there a way I can continue to play animal jam play wild without doing the "ask your parents" thingy

Tags: ios, animal-jam

Many months a go I made a animal jam play wild account but it had a thing where after a set amount of days you can't play until you ask your parents to activate.

I am 14 but I don't have an email i just type in random stuff and it works.

Is there a way to continue play when my time is up? will I have to keep making accounts each time my time is up to "ask my parents".

Comment: I read the edit and it said "removed noise"... why does it say noise instead of caps

Comment: because aside from convert the all caps to lower case most of it was, in my opinion, noise which detracts from the actual question (also i forgot about the final paragraph when i made the tag)

Answer (score 4):

The "ask your parents thingy" is an in-game purchase which you need to pay to continue playing, and you should indeed ask your parents to get through that screen.

That screen's there for a reason.